# Safari showing border of transparent PNG

Tags: safari, graphics, image-editing, websites

A website I work on has a partly transparent png image overlying parts of the website. The image is resized to 100% of the browser window width. In all other browsers the transparent parts behave normal – but safari shows a thin outline whee the image should be transparent.

I hope the screenshot makes the problem clear:

[image]

Now I'm wondering if this is this a bug – or a feature? And of course I would like to get rid of that zigzag line – so any suggestions and pointers are welcome. Thank you!

EDIT:

1. Yes, I checked if the image has a grey line – but it does not.
2. Also this problem anly appeared after I updated Safari to 11.0.2.
3. And when modifying the img's width in dev tools first to the actual width (7000px) and then back to 100% the grey line disappears.
4. Here is a [link to the website](https://rambazamba-theater.de/team/kristina-ohmen/) where the problem appears.

Comment: Can you share the image itself? I suspect the grey outline is part of the image, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549498/chrome-adding-gray-outline-to-printed-transparent-png-gif

Comment: Please provide the URL to the actual image, not some screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The image has however no grey line. Also this problem anly appeary after I updated Safari to 11.0.2. 
And when modifying the width in dev tools first to the actual width (7000px) and then back to 100% the grey line disappears. (updated the question accordingly)

Comment: I'm on Safari 11.0.1 and I'm not seeing any line. Definitely a bug though.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue and stumbled upon this question.

For me, the image showed a thin, medium-dark, shadowy border at the edge between the non-transparent and the transparent part of the image.
The issue was only visible in Safari.

[image: Comparison of the rendered image with the thin border in safari and the original image with transparency visualized]

For me, the solution was to simple add `transform: translateZ(0px)` to the image. This changes the rendering of the image in a way that prevents the border.

---

However, you might want to restrict this fix to Safari since it causes the image to be rendered pixelated in Chrome.